# Adding an entity to database with a navigation property that already exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following object which was send to the server with a request to be aded to the database:

```
var foo = new Foo 
{
    Id = 0,
    Name = "Foo",
    Bar = new Bar 
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Bar"
    }
}
```

`foo` needs to be added to the database.  `Bar` may already exist in the database, so if it does, it should not be added again.  If the `Bar` that i just recieved is different from the one in the database, (ie `Name` is different) then the Database should be updated to reflect the new `Bar`

I have tried the following code snippets, and they do not work:

```
void Insert (Foo foo)
{
    var bar = context.bars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Foo.Bar.Id)
    if (bar != null)
    {
        context.bars.attach(foo.Bar)

        // doesn't work because the search 
        //I just preformed already bound an object 
        //with this ID to the context, 
        //and I can't attach another with the same ID.  
        //Should I somehow "detach" the bar
        //that I got from the search result first? 
    }
    context.Foo.add(foo)
}

void Insert (Foo foo)
{
    var bar = context.bars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Foo.Bar.Id)
    if (bar != null)
    {
        bar = foo.Bar

        // successfully updates the object in the Database,
        // But does not stop the insert below from
        // trying to add it again, throwing a SQL Error
        // for violating the PRIMARY KEY constraint.
    }
    context.Foo.add(foo)
}
```

Am I missing something?  I feel like doing something like this shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: This article about the pitfalls of adding object graphs might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: Vote for Merge Disconnected Object Graph here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/432661

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second part is nearly right, you aren't actually updating `foo.Bar` though which is why I assume it's attempting to create a new one, try

```
var bar = context.bars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Foo.Bar.Id);
if (bar != null)
{
    bar.Name = foo.Bar.Name;
    foo.Bar = bar;
}
context.Foo.add(foo);
```

Comment: There really isn't a more generic way to do it than by manually mapping the properties?  seems like it would make refactoring sort of a pain.

Comment: Well there are [mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) libraries that make your life easier with this kind of stuff. However, they are kinda out with the scope of the question. Alternatively, you could try messing about with the internal properties of the entity e.g. [Working with Entity Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd283139(v=vs.100).aspx), to try *replace* the existing one with the new...I think the manual mapping is safer though.

Comment: Absolutely; I already have Automapper in my project, so i'm just fine with using it.  I just thought that there would be a more "Build in" way of doing it.  Just put it in my code, and works like a charm!

Comment: If you call `DbEntityEntry entry = Context.Entry(bar)` then you will be able to call `entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(foo.Bar)` instead of using AutoMapper  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679336(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: @Colin after calling those methods, do I have to do anything before calling `foo.Bar = bar` since we did all of the work with `entry`, a seperate object?  do we need to "refresh" `bar` first or anything?

Comment: No I don't think you do. But isn't the call to Add still trying to Add a Bar that already exists? foo.Bar is disconnected. bar is connected. When you call Add they both have their state changed to Added. That is only correct when you want to add. "Disconnected Graphs Are Complicated" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx. "Save the Grief and Use That Foreign Key".